# Prove that if $b \mid c$ then $ab \mid c$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This is an exercise in a text I am reading.

> Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be elements of a commutative ring, and suppose that $a$ is a unit. Prove that $b$ divides $c$ if and only if $ab$ divides $c$.

If $ab$ divides $c$ then there is no problem proving that $b$ divides $c$.  However I do not believe the converse is true.  Consider the commutative ring $(\mathbb{Z}_7, +_7, \cdot_7)$.  Letting $b=2$, $c=4$, and $a = 6$, we have $2 \mid 4$ but $2 \cdot_7 6 = 5 \not\mid 4$.

Am I missing something or is there an error in my textbook?

Comment: The ring you give in your example is actually a field, so every element is divisible by every other nonzero element.

Comment: $5\cdot 5=4$ ${}{}{}$

Comment: OK I think I see this now.  So if b|c there is an x such that bx=c and since a has an inverse we can say a(a^-1*bx) =c.  Does that look right?

Comment: Almost but not quite - this is where commutativity comes in. To conclude $ab\vert c$ we need some $y$ such that $aby=c$. Taking $y=a^{-1}x$ works *if the ring is commutative*, since then we have $aby=aba^{-1}x=aa^{-1}bx=bx=c,$ but without commutativity this doesn't necessarily work.

Comment: Yes. thanks for this point.  I see that Matt Samuel has the proof now.

Comment: @Geoffrey It follows immediately by *transitivity* of divisibility (just like the other direction) - see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $b\mid c$ then 
$$c=bd$$
for some $d$. Furthermore,
$$ac=abd$$
so
$$c=ab(a^{-1}d)$$
Hence $ab\mid c$.

The ring you give in your example is a field, so every nonzero element divides every other element.

Comment: A good exercise for the OP: show that (1) the assumption that $a$ is a unit can't be removed, and (2) the property "For all $b, c$, $b\vert c\iff ab\vert c$" is actually *equivalent to* "$a$ is a unit."

Comment: For(1) would you agree that a valid counter example could be R=({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, mod 8 addition and multiplication).  Letting  b=3, c=6 and a =4 (not a unit).  Then 3|6 but 3*4==4 does not divide 6.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer Yes that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

5 divides 4 so there is no error.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ ab\mid \underbrace{a^{-1}ab}_{\large b}\mid c\,\Rightarrow\,ab\mid c\,\ $ by *transitivity* of divisibility.